# Select value with largest difference to a range

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in long format which is organised in this way:

```r
help<- read.table(text="
ID     Sodium  H
1      140     31.9         
1      138     29.6          
1      136     30.6          
2      145     35.9
2      137     33.3
3      148     27.9
4      139     30.0
4      128     32.4
4      143     35.3
4      133     NA", header = TRUE)
```

I need the worst value in each subject (`ID`) for `Sodium` and `H`. The worst value for `H` is defined as either value furthest away from 41-49, while the worst value for sodium is defined as value furthest away from 134-154.

The end result should therefore become something like this:

```r
help<- read.table(text="
ID    Sodium  H
1     136     29.6         
2     137     33.3
3     148     27.9
4     128     30.0 ", header=TRUE)
```

What is the easiest way to do this? Using `aggregate` function or `dplyr`? Or something else? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tidy version:

```r
library(dplyr)
help %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.max(abs(H - 45))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#      ID DateTime         Sodium     H
#   <int> <chr>             <int> <dbl>
# 1     1 2020-07-27T11:00    138  29.6
# 2     2 2020-07-25T10:00    137  33.3
# 3     3 2020-07-27T14:00    148  27.9
# 4     4 2020-07-26T10:00    139  30
```

If it's possible that an ID may not have something out of limits, then the "worst" might return something within limits. If this is not desired, you can always add a filter to prevent within-limits:

```r
help %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.max(abs(H - 45))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(!between(H, 41, 49))
```

The premise for `Sodium` is the same, using `abs` and the difference between its value and the mean of the desired range:

```r
help %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  slice(which.max(abs(Sodium - 144))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 4 x 4
#      ID DateTime         Sodium     H
#   <int> <chr>             <int> <dbl>
# 1     1 2020-07-27T18:00    136  30.6
# 2     2 2020-07-25T10:00    137  33.3
# 3     3 2020-07-27T14:00    148  27.9
# 4     4 2020-07-26T12:00    128  32.4
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was the solution I was looking for.